# C4996 - SHA256, ошибка при сборке в VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sha256

Навшел исходники на sha256 решил интегрировать, Ругается на функцию 'sprintf'

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include "SHA256.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1

const unsigned int SHA256::sha256_k[64] = //UL = uint32
{ 0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
 0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
 0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
 0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
 0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
 0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
 0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
 0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2 };

void SHA256::transform(const unsigned char* message, unsigned int block_nb)
{
    uint32 w[64];
    uint32 wv[8];
    uint32 t1, t2;
    const unsigned char* sub_block;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)block_nb; i++) {
        sub_block = message + (i << 6);
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            SHA2_PACK32(&sub_block[j << 2], &w[j]);
        }
        for (j = 16; j < 64; j++) {
            w[j] = SHA256_F4(w[j - 2]) + w[j - 7] + SHA256_F3(w[j - 15]) + w[j - 16];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            wv[j] = m_h[j];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            t1 = wv[7] + SHA256_F2(wv[4]) + SHA2_CH(wv[4], wv[5], wv[6])
                + sha256_k[j] + w[j];
            t2 = SHA256_F1(wv[0]) + SHA2_MAJ(wv[0], wv[1], wv[2]);
            wv[7] = wv[6];
            wv[6] = wv[5];
            wv[5] = wv[4];
            wv[4] = wv[3] + t1;
            wv[3] = wv[2];
            wv[2] = wv[1];
            wv[1] = wv[0];
            wv[0] = t1 + t2;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            m_h[j] += wv[j];
        }
    }
}

void SHA256::init()
{
    m_h[0] = 0x6a09e667;
    m_h[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
    m_h[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
    m_h[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
    m_h[4] = 0x510e527f;
    m_h[5] = 0x9b05688c;
    m_h[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
    m_h[7] = 0x5be0cd19;
    m_len = 0;
    m_tot_len = 0;
}

void SHA256::update(const unsigned char* message, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int block_nb;
    unsigned int new_len, rem_len, tmp_len;
    const unsigned char* shifted_message;
    tmp_len = SHA224_256_BLOCK_SIZE - m_len;
    rem_len = len < tmp_len ? len : tmp_len;
    memcpy(&m_block[m_len], message, rem_len);
    if (m_len + len < SHA224_256_BLOCK_SIZE) {
        m_len += len;
        return;
    }
    new_len = len - rem_len;
    block_nb = new_len / SHA224_256_BLOCK_SIZE;
    shifted_message = message + rem_len;
    transform(m_block, 1);
    transform(shifted_message, block_nb);
    rem_len = new_len % SHA224_256_BLOCK_SIZE;
    memcpy(m_block, &shifted_message[block_nb << 6], rem_len);
    m_len = rem_len;
    m_tot_len += (block_nb + 1) << 6;
}

void SHA256::final(unsigned char* digest)
{
    unsigned int block_nb;
    unsigned int pm_len;
    unsigned int len_b;
    int i;
    block_nb = (1 + ((SHA224_256_BLOCK_SIZE - 9)
        < (m_len % SHA224_256_BLOCK_SIZE)));
    len_b = (m_tot_len + m_len) << 3;
    pm_len = block_nb << 6;
    memset(m_block + m_len, 0, pm_len - m_len);
    m_block[m_len] = 0x80;
    SHA2_UNPACK32(len_b, m_block + pm_len - 4);
    transform(m_block, block_nb);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        SHA2_UNPACK32(m_h[i], &digest[i << 2]);
    }
}

std::string sha256(std::string input)
{
    unsigned char digest[SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE];
    memset(digest, 0, SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE);

    SHA256 ctx = SHA256();
    ctx.init();
    ctx.update((unsigned char*)input.c_str(), input.length());
    ctx.final(digest);

    char buf[2 * SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE + 1];
    buf[2 * SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256::DIGEST_SIZE; i++)
        sprintf(buf + i * 2, "%02x", digest[i]);
    return std::string(buf);
}
```

При том что ошибка возникает только при сборке в VS, если собирать через gcc то все он.

Comment: 1. Зачем нам такая простыня? Выкладывайте только проблемное место. 2. Приведите сообщение об ошибке. 3. В функциии `sprintf`, которая в самом низу, ошибок не вижу.

Comment: Заголовок `<cstdio>` случайно не забыли?

Answer (score -3):

Нашел решение, в Препроцессор->Определения препроцессора добавил `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` Может кто-то объеснить как это работает?

Comment: Это не решение, это просто затычка, которая прячет проблемы. Поэтому всё-таки приведите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Ошибка C4996 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. tr e:\vc\tr\tr\sha256.cpp 131

Comment: @Red ¿Что непонятно в этом сообщении об ошибке? Там же написано, что следует делать.

Comment: Как работает? Да просто отключает сообщение, только и всего. Вы этим макросом как бы говорите "да, я беру на себя ответственность за использование опасных функций". Компилятор и умолкает.